# How to make a red zig zag under word in JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane, underline

I need to make a simple spell checker in Java for an application that I am creating and I have searched around and have not found any straight and to the point answers.

How do I make a word in `JEditorPane` get underlined with a red zig-zag? Like this:

[image: Red zig-zag]

Please if any one has any simple and fairly easy to implement ideas please would you share them with me.  Maybe even some links to some code.

Answer (score 4):

You may find this custom editor kit [example](http://java-sl.com/editor_kit_tutorial_example.html) useful. It shows how to extend `StyledEditorKit` to add attribute to draw custom underline.

If you're up for a complete solution you can go with Jide's [StyledLabel](http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/swing/StyledLabel.html). Check it out [here](http://www.jidesoft.com/articles/StyledLabel.pdf). It should be part of `jide-oss` - common open source library.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom Highlighter. See [Squiggle Painter](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/rectangle-painter/) as an example.

Answer (score 1):

I use [jtstand's editor](http://jtstand.codehaus.org/dependency-info.html) and [`SquiggleUnderlineHighlightPainter`](https://svn.codehaus.org/jtstand/jtstand/tags/jtstand-1.5.7/jtstand-editor/src/main/java/org/fife/ui/rsyntaxtextarea/SquiggleUnderlineHighlightPainter.java), which is also based on javax classes. I use it like this:

```
JTextComponent editor = //... your editor component;
SquiggleUnderlineHighlightPainter sqpainter = new SquiggleUnderlineHighlightPainter(Color.RED);
try {
    editor.getHighlighter().addHighlight(beginPosition, endPosition, sqpainter);
} 
catch (BadLocationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This should work with any `javax.swing.text.JTextComponent`, including `JEditorPane`. See [addHighlighter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Highlighter.html#addHighlight%28int,%20int,%20javax.swing.text.Highlighter.HighlightPainter%29).